# Python Array Parsing

Tags: python, arrays, string, comparison

I am super new to python and I am running into a stupid problem, this is my first Python code too...

I am splitting a string into an array and then I want to compare various elements. I am printing the array beforehand to get a list of elements, so I am sure my count is right. Code is below:

To print array

```
def printarray(a):
     for i in range (0,len(a)):
         print( "%s - %s " % (i, a[i]) )
     print("\n\n\n--------\n\n\n")

Output:
0 - 2014-04-08
1 - 19:00:02,336
2 - INFO
3 - core.SolrCore
.....
```

I am trying to parse it now:

```
if temp[2] is "INFO":
    print (temp[2])
```

I can't figure out why this is not evaluating to true. I can't get this to work. I've tried comparing with **is**, double, single quotes, nothing is working. I've tried sample code, where I assign this value to an array and run a comparison that way and it works with exact same code.

```
d = ['INFO']
if d[0] is 'INFO':
    print("works")
```

This is making me appreciate perl more and more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test for string equality with `==` not `is`. `is` tests that it's the same object in memory. This is certainly not guaranteed for strings, though it frequently is, as Python tries to avoid creating the same string over and over in memory.

Typically we use `is` to look for singletons like `None`.

If that doesn't work, I recommend you investigate by checking the type, length and representation of the string.

do this:

```
word = temp[2]
type(word) # expect str
len(word) # expect 4
print repr(word) # expect 'INFO'
```